# How to write a condition inside select statement in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

My Scenario is I have the following table -

```
FullName                 ManufacturingCost
------------------------------------------
Harry Singh Malhotra          $200.00
Harry                         $200.00
Danny                         $200.00
Britany Krout                 $100.00
```

Now I want two columns from the above table - `fullName` and `FirstName`. I am using this query:

```
Select 
    fullName, left(fullName, charindex(' ', fullName, 1) - 1) as firstName
from 
    Table1
```

The problem in the above query is that in the second and the third row `Firstname` is returned as `Null` because `charindex` could not find `' '` in these rows.

I want the result as:

```
    FullName                 FirstName
    -------------------------------------
    Harry Singh Malhotra     Harry
    Harry                    Harry
    Danny                    Danny
    Britany Krout            Britany
```

Can someone help me in letting me know how to add conditions inside the statement

```
select * from Table11
```

because I want to check a condition for each value in a particular column.

Select case does not work because it takes only scalar values.

Comment: The **REAL** solution would be to store those things (`FirstName`, `LastName`) as **separate columns** - adding them together into a `FullName` is just sooooooo much simpler than parsing a full name into first and last name .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Case Statement` to handle `FullName` with no `Middlename` or `LastName`

```
SELECT fullName,
       First_Name=LEFT(( fullName ), CASE
                                       WHEN Charindex(' ', fullName) = 0 THEN Len(fullName)
                                       ELSE Charindex(' ', fullName)
                                     END)
FROM   Table1
```

`ParseName` trick will also work but your string should have at max 4 words.

```
SELECT fullName,
       First_Name=Reverse(Parsename(Replace(Reverse(fullName), ' ', '.'), 1))
FROM   table1
```

Comment: @sam - Gald it helped check the parsename answer